# OpenGL ES 2 Texture atlas bleeding edge

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0, artifact

Currently working on video games project.

When I get:

```
Matrix.orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, 0,  widthwindows,  heightwindows, 0, -1, 3);
```

Everything looks ok. But when the variable `widthwindows` is different from the real screen resolution now I get this effect.

[image]

I can't use precited solution from other topic because some of my tiles are curve or whatever so even with `-0.5 pixel` there are no effect on them they still get transparency around them (and even some tiles aren't in taking `64*64`, but `12*64` for instance, so `-0.5 pixel` get no effect).

Comment: I would try disabling mip mapping on this atlas, but that will probably cause other problems, anyway you can try.

Comment: Already done , and no change. After using gemserk process on the texture atlas by a friend as i dont know how to launch that one. It seem to dont get transparent border anymore BUT i still get them when i move the matrix from left or right. I dont get them when i'm at position 0 and max range for example . So 2 things , first if someone could help me launche that : [link](https://github.com/gemserk/imageprocessing) and if someone understand why when i move the matrix scaled it always appear ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to work with PMA(Pre Multiplied Alpha).
When you draw a sprite with transparency you many times use a Normal blending mode.
A normal blending mode takes the sprite's pixel color multiplies it by the Alpha of that pixel and adds it to the background pixel color multipled by 1 compliment of the source pixel alpha.
This works most of the time however when scaling and filtering the sprite this might cause semi transparent pixels to appear darker than they should.

In order to solve this you use PMA.
Since in the blending you are going to multiply the sprite's color with the sprite's alpha, you can instead store the pixel color already multiplied by it's alpha.
Now the blending mode will look like this... Add PMA pixel color(without multiplying  the alpha) to the background color multiplied by 1's compliment of the source pixel alpha.

In GLES 2 the Normal blending mode will be like this:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The PMA blending mode will look like this:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Hope this solves your issue.